# If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda^*(A)>0$ then $A$ contains a measurable subset that is not Borel.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda^*(A)>0$ then it contains a subset which is not Borel but Lebesgue measurable.

I don't know if the statement is true. Can someone provide some hint?

Comment: **Hint:** Similar to how this works for the Cantor middle thirds set. Any such set $A$ contains a subset $Z$ of measure zero with cardinality continuum, and most (in the sense of cardinality) of the subsets of $Z$ are measurable and not Borel.

Comment: The answer by @Pelota (+1) shows that I overlooked the possibility that a non-measurable set can have inner measure zero (positive inner measure implies existence of a positive measure closed set, and then what I said carries through), which is rather embarrassing given the number of times I've posted about the more extreme notion of a saturated nonmeasurable set (e.g. see the beginning of *II. BERNSTEIN SETS* in this [5 February 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/sxp7dgz9zTYJ); incidentally, add "B is uncountable" to (d) and (e)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144529/does-every-set-of-reals-contain-a-measure-zero-set-of-the-same-cardinality-does) has been asked on MO. Here I shall try to be more explicit, but most of what I write below was already said in the answers to the linked question.

If the set is measurable, the result is true: by regularity, $A$ contains a compact uncountable subset $C:0<\mu(C)<+\infty$. By Cantor-Bendixson, $C=P\cup Q$ with $P$ perfect, $Q$ countable. Mimicking the usual construction of a Cantor set, we get a subset $R$ of $P$ of measure $0$ and cardinality of the continuum.Now, every subset of $R$ is Lebesgue measurable. Since there are $2^\mathfrak c$ subsets of $R$ and only $\mathfrak c$ Borel sets, it's clear that there is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $A$ which is not Borel.

In general, *the answer is independent from ZFC*:

For the answer to be no, there must exist a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$, such that it does not contain any uncountable null subset (otherwise, the same cardinality reasoning as before yields a Lebesgue measurable non Borel subset **EDIT**: as @Dave L. Renfro noted in the comments this requires an additional hypotesis, the requirement that $2^{\aleph_1}>2^{\aleph_0}$, which is known as Luzin's hypotesis. The claim is still valid since LH is independent from ZFC). Such a set $S$ is called a [Sierpiński set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_set), and its existence is independent from ZFC.
We have proved that, if there is no Sierpiński set, the answer is positive. It remains to prove that if a Sierpiński set exists, the answer is no:
let $B\subset S$ be a Lebesgue measurable set.
It's easy to see that it can be written as $C\cup N$, where $C$ is a Borel set and $N$ is a null set. Since $S$ is Sierpinski and $N\subset B\subset S$, $N$ is countable. Thus $B=C\cup N$ is Borel measurable.

As a final note, it is not hard to prove (using transfinite induction) that the continuum hypotesis implies the existence of a Sierpinski set:

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of Borel sets of measure $0$. It is easy to see that $|\mathcal{B}|=\mathfrak c$. Let us well order $\mathcal{B}$ as $\{b_\lambda\}_{\{\lambda<\omega_1\}}$ ($\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal).
For every $\lambda<\omega_1$, let $x_\lambda$ be so that $x_\lambda\not\in \cup_{\alpha<\lambda} b_\alpha$ (this is possible since the union has measure $0$). If we define $S=\{x_\lambda\}$, it is easy to see that $S$ has at most countable intersection with Borel sets of measure $0$. Since every null set is contained in a null Borel set (by outer regularity), the result follows.

Comment: It seems that you are using too much of heavy theories.

Comment: *For the answer to be no* --- Unless I'm missing something (and I might, as I'm not looking over this very carefully now, being busy with something else), I think more is needed here because it's consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_1}$ (and  $2^{\aleph_0} < 2^{\aleph_1}$ is also consistent). This is sometimes called "Lusin's Hypothesis" (or "second continuum hypothesis") because Lusin (also written Luzin) first drew attention to whether equality holds sometime back in the 1920s.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You are right. I was thinking about the other implication and that it slipped past me. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @epsilon_delta I am sorry about that, although I do not believe there is any easier proof of this result. In my experience (mind that I'm not a set theorist by any stretch of the word, so this is really only my opinion) this often happens in measure theory: reasonable statements turn out to be related to deep set theoretic questions: see e.g. [borel conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_measure_zero_set).